# online automatic wallpaper changer

Tags: customization, wallpaper

I use a tool called [variety](https://launchpad.net/variety) which sets automatic wallpaper to my Linux machines via various websites like deviantart, wallpapers.net, flickr etc.

Is there such tool for MacOSX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Irvue, by Leonspok.  You can get it on the Mac App Store and [here](http://irvue.tumblr.com).  It uses fantastic-looking, hi-res images from Unsplash.

Comment: can i also choose they type of wallpaper it downloads? Category? I want gaming wallpapers

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan Not with Irvue, no.